# Saving JPEG metada using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, metadata, jpeg

Is there any way I could save some JPEG metadata (like Exposure Time) using OpenCV 2.4.2?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK there is no OpenCV support for EXIF-Data. I think you need to use a external library like [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VideoCapture properties](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cv.getcaptureproperty#cv.GetCaptureProperty) to retrieve information from images (frames).

I use [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) to create exif tags and write the retrieved info to those images.

Comment: I am not working with videos, therefore VideoCapture properties won't work for me. I was looking for something with cv::imwrite, however turns out you can't do it without a third party library. Thanks anyway.